# PrimeNG: Drag & Drop between Trees in two different components

Tags: tree, drag-and-drop, primeng

I'am working on Drag & Drop between two PrimeNG trees.

I added two trees in one component and get a console log (for test purpose)

navigator.component.html

```
<p-tree [value]="nodes" 
   [draggableNodes]="true" [droppableNodes]="true" 
   droppableScope="navigator" draggableScope="contents" 
   (onNodeExpand)="loadNodes($event)">
</p-tree>
<p-tree [value]="destnodes" [draggableNodes]="true" [droppableNodes]="true"
    droppableScope="contents" draggableScope="navigator" 
    [validateDrop]="true" (onNodeDrop)="onNodeDrop($event)" >
</p-tree>
```

navigator.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from 'primeng/api';
import { TreeDragDropService } from 'primeng/api';
import { NodeService } from 'src/app/services/nodeservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigator',
  templateUrl: './navigator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigator.component.css'],
  providers: [TreeDragDropService]
  
})

export class NavigatorComponent implements OnInit {

  nodes: TreeNode[];
  destnodes: TreeNode[];

  constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // some code to initialize the root nodes
  }

  loadNodes(event) {
     // some code to load...
    }
  }

  onNodeDrop( event ) {
    console.log( "Drop");
    console.log( event );
  }
}
```

This works fine, I'am getting the console messages.

But...if I copy and paste the second tree into a new component, the onNodeDrop never be called.

Does I make something wrong or is it generally not implemented ?